# Some images returning 404 in react app when deployed to Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service

I have a React App which uses the following block of code to display images from the public/ directory:

```
const getBuildingImagePath = () => {
    const path = `/assets/img/buildings/${technicalreference}.webp`;
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = path;
    img.onerror = () => (img.src = PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE);
    return img.src;
  };
...
return (
    <Card>
      <Link to={`/buildings/profile/${buildingid}`}>
        <Card.Img
          src={getBuildingImagePath()}
          alt="Building Image"
          className="card-img-aspect"
          onError={handleError}
        />
```

And this has worked well for a long time.

However, today I added a few more images to the directory, tested in my local environment, and displaying as expected. Working while running the app in development environment, working when serving a build of my app on my local host. So I pushed the build up to Azure App Services, which is when I encountered the issue of *some* of the images returning a 404 error.

One of the new images is displaying correctly - when browsing to https://myapp.website.com/assets/img/buildings/workingimage.webp it displays. But when I browse to https://myapp.website.com/assets/img/buildings/someotherimages.webp I'm getting a 404 error returned by my react app.

I've checked the build and using Azure's Advanced Tools (Kudu) I can browse wwwroot and in wwwroot/assets/img/buildings/ I can see all of the images I expect, and display them in my browser... yet I get this 404 error when trying to load them in my code / browse from the app domain. It's basically as though my React app isn't serving those specific images - which seems odd, because it's serving all of the others.

I'm bewildered by what could be causing this - why some images load and others do not, despite all images being present and correct in the build directory.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot would be very welcome.

**Update:**
The latest troubleshooting I've done:

1. Upload an image called image.jpeg, and browse to it at https://myapp.website.com/assets/img/buildings/image.jpeg - works.
2. Rename image to image.webp and browse to it at https://myapp.website.com/assets/img/buildings/image.webp - works.
3. Rename image to onlEQ2.webp and browse to it at https://myapp.website.com/assets/img/buildings/onlEQ2.webp - works.
4. Rename image to onlEQ.webp and browse to it at https://myapp.website.com/assets/img/buildings/onlEQ.webp - 404 error.

Where onlEQ.webp is the original image name I uploaded when this issue first arose. Lots of other similar named images such as onlSQ.webp work just fine... Have cleared caches, tried on different devices, tried on different internet connections.

Comment: "*It's basically as though my React app isn't serving those specific images*" your react app isn't serving anything, because react is a client-side only technology. (You may be using something like next or similar to do serverside rendering though). Are you serving your assets through a backend you built yourself or are you just using the paths from azure?

Comment: If all the images are there where you expect them, one possibility is that you are generating wrong paths for them. Use the developertools of your browser and insepect such an missing image, if its `src` is pointing to the path you expect and if that image exists at this path

Comment: And if you are using some kind of selfmade backend, also check if you have some restrictions there or try to attach some error logging when it's to return a 404 ...

Comment: Sorry, I meant the pm2 server that azure runs the app on. The 404 page from my react app is being returned for the specific image paths that aren’t working, but I know the paths are correct as all of the other images at the same path (with a different file name) are being displayed correctly.

Comment: Well there are only two possibilities: either the path you are requesting doesn't exist or your backend isn't serving correctly. But with that little amount of info you are giving us, it's hard to say anything...

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your suggestions. It's hard to describe or give a URL to demonstrate due to the authentication required to access the app. I've updated the above with some more stuff I've done to test the issue. I can upload an image, and it works, until I rename it to the specific string(s) that weren't working previously and I get a 404 error... Very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

Frustratingly, I hadn't considered that my Azure App Service is residing behind Azure Front Door, and caching was enabled. This meant that the 404 error, having been produced once for a given URL, was cached. Once the resource was available at the URL the cached 404 response was still being returned.

Turning off caching on the Azure Front Door service resolved my issue.